# Netty and webDAV, any compatibility?

Tags: netty, webdav, file-transfer

I'm working on content server with Netty, so i'm building a personalized server, i was wondering if i can use webDAV protocole with Netty?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any server webdav solution based on netty, but I think [async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client), which use netty as one of its possible providers, has a client implementation.

But, of course, since webDAV is based on HTTP you can always roll your own based on the existing netty http code ;-)

Comment: And of course we would love to accept the codec for webdav as pull-req ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Miltion (http://milton.io/). It's based on Jetty.